# PHP regex check length without using lookahead

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

Looked at 2 other regex related questions and both were vastly beyond what I need help with X'D.

```
<?php 

$userName = trim($_POST['username']);
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z].*(?(\d)).{8,}$/", $userName)){
    
    echo 'woot!';
```

I'm not really sure why its failing. I know its checking the first character must be alpha, then go more * but check at the end if its a digit ?(\d)... But why wont it check if the length of my $userName is 8 or more?

if I do

```
... *(?(\d){8,}
```

Its going to look for 8 or more digits as opposed to if the string itself is 8 or more.

> User must: start with letter, only end in numbers, and can only contain alphaNumeric, must be at least characters 8 long, and treat lower and uppercase the same. Which is to say I need to add an i at the end of my regex.

---

As so there is no way to work it into a regex aside form look aheads? `^...$.{8,}` wouldn't work?

Comment: Please clearly tell us what the rules are for a username?  It is clear that it must start with a letter, and also have a digit at some later point.  The rest is not clear.

Comment: User must: start with letter, only end in numbers, and can only contain alphaNumeric, must be atleast characters 8 long, and treat lower and uppercase the same.

Which is to say I need to add an i at the end of my regex.

Answer (score 3):

> User must: start with letter, only end in numbers, and can only contain alphaNumeric, must be at least characters 8 long, and treat lower and uppercase the same.

You may use this *simple* regex to meet this requirement:

```
^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z\d]{6,}\d$
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[A-Za-z]`: Match an ASCII letter at the start
- `[a-zA-Z\d]{6,}`: Match a letter or digit 6 or more times
- `\d`: Match a digit before end
- `$`: end

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ZEGiM/1)

Comment: You could simplify this to `^[A-Z][A-Z\d]{6,}\d$` and use it in case insensitive mode.

Comment: Yes true we could use `/i` like that. I guess I just wanted to give complete solution in regex only for readability purpose otherwise `/^[A-Z][A-Z\d]{6,}\d$/gmi` is shorter.

Comment: @Coding_Noob: Did this solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex pattern:

```regex
^(?=.{8,}$)[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[0-9]+$
```

Sample script:

```php
$userName = trim($_POST['username']);
if (preg_match("/^(?=.{8,}$)[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[0-9]+$/i", $userName)) {
    echo "MATCH";
}
```

Of note, the regex pattern uses `(?=.{8,}$)` at the start of the pattern.  This is a positive *lookahead*, which asserts that the match is at least 8 characters.

If you don't want to use a lookahead, you may just explicitly check the username length using `strlen()`:

```php
$userName = trim($_POST['username']);
if (preg_match("/^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[0-9]+$/i", $userName) &&
    strlen($userName) >= 8) {
    echo "MATCH";
}
```

Comment: Ye I saw a few things regarding look aheads; is there any way to do this without? We havent covered that in the course I'm in, and I'd really like to understand why its not working as is with my regex; or how it could work :) ?

Comment: Use `strlen()` to check the number of characters?

Comment: As so theres no way to work it into a regex aside form look aheads?

^...$.{8,} wouldn't work?

Comment: (You could omit the last `+` after `[0-9]+` as the character class before it also matches digits )